# Zxing: do i need to preprocess image?

Tags: java, zxing

I am using Zxing to read QRCodes from a video camera, but the read results are very unstable.

The image seen by the camera is static, and so is the camera itself. However, when the cam takes, say, 100 images, only on some of them will the qr codes be read (or even found).

The image is FullHD and colour, qrcodes vary in sizes but are always big and clear enough to be read off the screen by an iPhone app (not based on zxing). My app is not for Android or iOs.

My question is: should i somehow preprocess the image by, say, making it monochrome/greyscale, etc? Should i try and find the possible location of a barcode myself and then give zxing only the part of the image that possibly contains the barcode? In other words, how can I improve the result and make it more stable?

Comment: This isn't really answerable without showing some example images. No, you do not need to preprocess. Something else is wrong with how you are using the library.

Comment: Make sure you set the "try_harder" option, by default zxing looks only at the center of the image.

Comment: @Durandal try_harder was the first thing I tried. Didn't help. I will try to post some sample images as soon as I can.